# Paginacion en AngularJS (Angular 1) utilizando ng-change

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Estoy utilizando :

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/pagination/docs

Mi duda es la sgte:

```
<uib-pagination ng-change="test(this, name)" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></uib-pagination>
```

y mi js

```
$scope.test = function(page, name) {
    alert(page + name)
};
```

El name me llega bien pero en page me llega el objecto,

- ¿Cómo puedo obtener la página que le he dado?
- Supongamos que en total tenga 10 000 datos y si muestro de 10 en 10 me sale 100 botones de páginación, como puedo hacer que solo me salgan 10 por ejemplo pero sin usar el max-size ya que con eso solo podria ver los 100 primeros registros

Comment: Si el objeto que te llega con la referencia `this` no es el que esperas (la página), entonces me parece que la referencia `this` no es lo que deberías pasarle. ¿Has probado otras opciones?

Answer (score 0):

**¿Cómo puedo obtener la página que le he dado?**

ng-change es llamado después de que el model es modificado, por lo tanto simplemente podes hacer:

```
$scope.test = function(angularObj, name) {
    alert($scope.currentPage);
};
```

Si por algun motivo necesitas obtener el current page desde el objeto que envias, podes hacer:

```
$scope.test = function(angularObj, name) {
    alert(angularObj.currentPage);
};
```

**Supongamos que en total tenga 10 000 datos y si muestro de 10 en 10 me sale 100 botones de paginación, como puedo hacer que solo me salgan 10 por ejemplo pero sin usar el max-size ya que con eso solo podría ver los 100 primeros registros**

Tenes un error de concepto, usa max-size y empezá a irte hacia la derecha, después que haces click en 10, la botonera cambia y te muestra del 11 al 20. Si querés ver cambios en CADA pagina que haces click, hace rotate=true. Andá a la documentación que comparto debajo y hace click en cada ejemplo, ahí está claro que hace cada opción

```
<uib-pagination ng-change="test(this, name)" max-size="maxSizeVar" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" rotate="true"></uib-pagination>
```

**Documentación:**

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination